# ZeroMQ with ACE Reactor

Tags: c++, zeromq, ace

I have a legacy application that handles communication using the ACE Reactor.  To improve reliability across temporary network partitions, I would like to use ZeroMQ, instead of TCP sockets, as the transport.  ACE provides C++ wrappers for *existing* IPC mechanisms, but I want to provide a *custom* IPC mechanism that ACE can use.  In my particular case I want to use zmq, but my question is more general and I am asking, how can I use a custom transport with ACE?

Comment: Are you trying to ask whether anyone has access to the ACE framework source-code documentation? ZeroMQ can intelligently mediate even the original TCP-originated transport-links accross non-native transport-routes, if one wishes to, so as a last resort, you can do the same.

Comment: If you have some source code that understand BSD sockets, and you don't want to make many changes to it, you might care to take a look at http://nanomsg.org. It's very similar in philosphy to ZeroMQ, but its function prototypes are closer to the BSD socket function prototypes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this.

1. Derive a new family of IPC classes from `ACE_SOCK` or maybe `ACE_IPC_SAP`, depending on what ZeroMQ gives you for a model. Don’t forget the address class to match. This is a lot of work but may be worth it if you will reuse it in many places.
2. Derive a handler for your use case from `ACE_Event_Handler` and include a member that is your ZeroMQ transfer object. Assuming you can get a selectable socket handle from the ZeroMQ object you can access it from the `get_handle()` hook and register it with the reactor. Then from your `handle_input()` et al callbacks do the message transfer. This is relatively quick and easy.